# Sending data via tcp ip using struct and union

Tags: c, tcp, struct, unions

Sorry for my poor english! I'm developing a program in C to send data via tcp ip. This program should use struct and union as follows (I'll put only the part of the code that matters):

***Server that sends data:

Uses a struct with the data that need to send:

```
struct movimentos{

    bool Frente;
    bool Esquerda;
    bool Direita;
    bool Parado;
    bool PassoDireita;
    bool PassoEsquerda;
}m;
```

And a union that includes these data and identifies the size of the structure:

```
union dados{

    movimentos m;
    char tamanho [(sizeof movimentos)];
}uniao;
```

and then, I use the 'send' function to send the address of this structure to the client:

```
send(winsock,uniao.tamanho,sizeof(uniao.tamanho),0);
```

*** Cliente that receives data:

Have a structure and union alike what the server has:

```
struct movimentos{

    bool Frente;
    bool Esquerda;
    bool Direita;
    bool Parado;
    bool PassoDireita;
    bool PassoEsquerda;
}move;

union dados{

    movimentos move;
    char tamanho [(sizeof movimentos)];
}uniao;
```

function 'recv' to receive the socket and the Union address:

```
int bytes=recv(winsock,uniao.tamanho,sizeof(uniao.tamanho),0);
```

My problem is the following ******

I want to use the values ​​of the struct sent by the server that client. But I do not know how to do this. I want to know how to get those data received to be able to manipulate the action within the program.

Thanks!

Comment: you mean client want to receive data in same structure format you mentioned?

Comment: This is a very poor idea. Don't use structs as network protocols. You are introducing about half a dozen unwanted dependencies. Define a wire protocol in octets, and write yourself a library to send and receive it.

Answer (score 0):

use **sprintf_s** and **vsscanf**.

In server side create formatted string using your structure with the help of [sprintf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx) then send.

In client side use [vsscanf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280924.aspx) to read formatted data .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~SENDER
movimentos movi;
//send your struct by giving it's address
send(winsock, &movi, sizeof(movimentos), 0);
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~RECEIVER
movimentos movi;
int bytes = recv(winsock, &movi, sizeof(movimentos), 0);
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~RECEIVER 2 (BETTER)
movimentos movi;
BYTE buffer[1024]; //for example
int bytes = recv(winsock, buffer, 1024, 0);
memcpy((void*)&movi, (void*)buffer, sizeof(movimentos));
```

Comment: This is not sufficient - because TCP is a stream transport rather than directly exposing a packet one, you can't be sure that the call to recv() will get you a struct's worth of bytes, or even if it does, that those are necessarily all from the same struct - it might get you less, and it might get the tail end of one and the beginning of the next.  Plus there's the assumption that the struct is stored in identical ways on both systems.